# Precedence Python % and /

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't understand the order between modulo operator and division in Python 2.7

Image: [Precedence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5jOA.jpg)

In Python Shell:

```
>>> 86%3/10
0
>>> 86/3%10
8
```

first module ??? second division??

Thanks.

Comment: Left to right: `86%3=2`, `2/10=0`. `86/3=28`, `28%10=8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have the same precedence and evaluate left-to-right.
so `86%3/10` is equivalent to `((86%3)/10)` and `86/3%10` is equivalent to `((86/3)%10)`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 86%3/10 -> 86%3 = 2 -> 2/10 = 0
0
>>> 86/3%10 -> 86/3 = 28 -> 28%10 = 8
8
```

if you want float number

```
>>> 86%3/10.0
0.2
>>> 86/3.0%10
8.666666666666668
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is [Leftmost Derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Derivations_and_syntax_trees).

/ * % are in same group but leftmost first

Answer (score 0):

If the precedence of two operation are equal (which is the case here i.e. % and  / have equal precedence), then in Python it goes from left to right.